# Pivot R dataframe longer by splitting a variable number of column values

Tags: r

Suppose the following data:

```
foo <- data.frame(
  key=c('one', 'two', 'three'), val=c('a', 'b|c', 'd|e|f'),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

It looks like

```
> foo
    key   val
1   one     a
2   two   b|c
3 three d|e|f
```

I want output that is as follows:

```
bar <- data.frame(key=c('one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three'),
                  val=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

That looks like

```
> bar
    key val
1   one   a
2   two   b
3   two   c
4 three   d
5 three   e
6 three   f
```

The psuedo-code might be: split `val` by pipe (`|`), but into a variable (unknown) number of columns, then pivot longer.

Suggestions?

Ideally using the tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the question I linked.  It will look like this:

```
bar <- foo %>% mutate(val=strsplit(val, "\\|")) %>% unnest(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nest and unnest, but actually it works without using `summarize()`:

```r
foo %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarize(val = unlist(str_split(val, pattern = "[|]"))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```